# In-place quicksort woes

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I've been struggling with this for too many hours now. I'm trying to build an in-place quicksort in Java following a [pseudocode example](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort). Yes, I've tried implemented the example verbatim, but it's got an infinite loop problem.  But anyway the logic seems sound, so I've been wrestling with fixing it for hours.

I can't for the life of me get the darn thing to work - here's an SSCCE using a trivial list: `15, 12, 13`. Things sort when I expect them, but then the sub-lists are not split correctly. If I remove pointers in the swap area, duplicates are not supported.  Can someone help out, or point me to a similar implementation that works (for which I've looked unsuccessfully)?

SSCCE, no traces:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quicksort {
public static void main(final String[] args0) {
    List<Integer> unsorted = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{15, 12, 13});

    int size = unsorted.size();
    int left = 0;
    int right = size - 1;
    int pivot = 13; // Median of first, middle, last. Method removed for brevity.

    while (left < right) {
        while (unsorted.get(left).compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
            left++;
        }

        while (unsorted.get(right).compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
            right--;
        }

        if (unsorted.get(left).compareTo(unsorted.get(right)) > 0) {
            int old = unsorted.get(left);
            unsorted.set(left, unsorted.get(right));
            unsorted.set(right, old);

            if (left + 1 < size) {
                left++;
            }
            if (right - 1 >= 0) {
                right--;
            }
        }           
    }

    System.out.println("List: " + unsorted);
    System.out.println("Sublist left: " + unsorted.subList(0, left));  // Yields [13, 15] 
    System.out.println("Sublist right: " + unsorted.subList(left, size)); // Yields [12]
    // ...then recurse for sublists.
}
}
```

---

SSCCE, with traces (same as above):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quicksort {
public static void main(final String[] args0) {
    List<Integer> unsorted = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{15, 12, 13});

    int size = unsorted.size();
    int left = 0;
    int right = size - 1;
    int pivot = 13; // Median of first, middle, last. Method removed for brevity.

    System.out.println("---Processing " + unsorted);
    System.out.println("Median " + pivot);
    System.out.println("Left = " + left + ", right = " + right);

    while (left < right) {
        System.out.println("Start INC/DEC, left = " + left + ", right = " + right);
        while (unsorted.get(left).compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
            left++;
        }

        while (unsorted.get(right).compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
            right--;
        }
        System.out.println("End INC/DEC, left = " + left + ", right = " + right);

        if (unsorted.get(left).compareTo(unsorted.get(right)) > 0) {
            int old = unsorted.get(left);
            unsorted.set(left, unsorted.get(right));
            unsorted.set(right, old);

            if (left + 1 < size) {
                left++;
            }
            if (right - 1 >= 0) {
                right--;
            }

            System.out.println("End swap, left = " + left + ", right = " + right + ", list now " + unsorted);
        }           
        System.out.println("End while, left = " + left + ", right = " + right + ", list now " + unsorted);
    }

    System.out.println("List: " + unsorted);
    System.out.println("Sublist left: " + unsorted.subList(0, left));
    System.out.println("Sublist right: " + unsorted.subList(left, size));
    // ...then recurse for sublists.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you compare values before swapping:

```
if (unsorted.get(left).compareTo(unsorted.get(right)) > 0)
```

while the reference code compares indices:

```
if left ≤ right
```

Also see the difference in comparison: `<=` instead of `>`.

Comment: Yep, looks like that was it (for now!) Thanks!